# Django -- dumppdata without being able to SSH into server

Tags: django, django-database

I can't ssh into server because of some foolish permissions mistakes I made. Doing a clean install, but want to recover the django data. Is there a way to dumpdata without being in the server? Maybe from the admin panel?

Comment: This may help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

Comment: You do not have permissions or ssh access? Can you login to DBMS and export db?